# Why can I use operator= but not operator== with C++11 brace-initializers?

Tags: c++, c++11

See this example:

```
struct Foo
{
    int a;
    int b;

    bool operator == (const Foo & x)
    {
        return a == x.a && b == x.b;
    }
};

int main ()
{
    Foo a;

    a = {1, 2};

    if (a == {1, 2}) // error: expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token
    {
    }
}
```

The line `a={1,2}` is fine. The braces are convert to a `Foo` to match the argument type of the implicit `operator=` method. It still works if `operator=` is user-defined.

The line `if (a=={1,2}})` errors as indicated.

Why does the expression `{1,2}` not convert to a `Foo` to match the user-defined `operator==` method?

Comment: This is with g++-4.7.

Comment: I don't see any explicit `operator==` in your code. Did you mean "user-defined"?

Comment: the fact that it is called initializer list rather than expression litteral might be a clue of the fact that it is not supported on purpose (although I didn't think about it before you asked).

Comment: You can write `if (a == Foo{1, 2})` instead.

Comment: I have started a discussion in hope this limitation will be lifted in a future version. Fee free to add a comment. https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-proposals/nXjimf0amus/nd-ilyXnFwAJ

Answer (score 41, accepted):

List-initialization cannot be used as an argument to an operator *in the general case*. Per Paragraph 8.5.4/1 of the C++11 Standard:

> [...] List-initialization can be used
>
> — as the initializer in a variable definition (8.5)
>
> — as the initializer in a new expression (5.3.4)
>
> — in a return statement (6.6.3)
>
> — as a for-range-initializer (6.5)
>
> — **as a function argument** (5.2.2)
>
> — as a subscript (5.2.1)
>
> — as an argument to a constructor invocation (8.5, 5.2.3)
>
> — as an initializer for a non-static data member (9.2)
>
> — in a mem-initializer (12.6.2)
>
> — **on the right-hand side of an assignment** (5.17)

The last item explains why list-initialization is allowed on the right side of `operator =`, even though it is not allowed in general for an arbitrary operator.

Because of the fifth item above, however, it can be used as an argument to a regular function call, this way:

```
if (a.operator == ({1, 2}))
```

Comment: @6502: Because the Standard says so (see the paragraph I quoted)

Comment: It's not that interesting really. _You_ try writing a robust and unambiguous language feature to support it.

Comment: @6502: That's what SO would call a "non-constructive" question I guess. I can't tell the rationale. Maybe someone from the Committee could, or some user with more experience/insight than me

Comment: `if(a.operator==({a,b}))` works, BTW. I guess this means the two forms are not as equivalent as I'd thought.

Comment: @spraff: Syntactically they are not, indeed. But semantically they are. Keep in mind that `{a, b}` is not an expression, just a syntactic language construct

Comment: An expression *is* just a syntactic language construct. What do you really mean?

Comment: @spraff: No, an expression (as per Clause 5 of the Standard) is something that can be evaluated and yields a value with a type and possibly side-effects (of course, expressions also require some syntax in order to be written, but that's not what I meant). On the other hand, `{a, b}` is not an expression - it does not have a type, it is just a language construct used for initialization. Its elements `a` and `b` are expressions, but `{a, b}` is not

Comment: The C++ standard quote here contradicts the first sentence. "On the right hand side of an assignment" means that the syntax is allowed with an operator. Just not with all of them.

Comment: @Kaz: OK, yes, I meant "not with an operator *in general*". I will edit to clarify this, thank yu

Comment: I would suggest _"even though it is not allowed in general for **arbitrary operators**."_ to make it even clearer, on my first reading I thought it said "not allowed for **any** operator" when your quote shows it's allowed for at least one operator :)

Comment: @6502 I believe current limitations are not justified. They are there only because parsing `{a,b}` on the LHS is hard-to-impossible without ambiguity, but on the RHS there should be no problem. Here is a discussion on the topic and a bit more info, feel free to add a comment: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-proposals/nXjimf0amus/nd-ilyXnFwAJ

Answer (score 7):

It's just simply not supported.

Initializer lists are explicitly defined to be valid in *initializations* (`[C++11: 8.5.4]`), and *assignments*:

> `[C++11: 5.17/9]:` A *braced-init-list* may appear on the right-hand side of
>
> - an assignment to a scalar, in which case the initializer list shall have at most a single element. The meaning of `x={v}`, where `T` is the scalar type of the expression `x`, is that of `x=T(v)` except that no narrowing conversion (8.5.4) is allowed. The meaning of `x={}` is `x=T()`.
> - an assignment defined by a user-defined assignment operator, in which case the initializer list is passed as the argument to the operator function.

There is no standard wording to allow other, arbitrary cases.

If it were allowed, in this example, the type of `{1,2}` would be fairly ambiguous. It would be a complicated language feature to implement.

Comment: What is the main logical difference between `operator=` and `operator==`? Both of them can take arbitrary types as RHS

Comment: I guess they treat assignment as a special case because of its similarities to initialisation.

Comment: I guess it could be defined to have whatever type the context of the statement requires. We already to this to decide whether a number is an int, float, or argument to a constructor, etc. Having `{1,2}` on its own need not have any meaning.

Comment: @6502 Do not ask about "logical difference". **This is C++**. C++ is not a design, but a rolling snowball that accumulates hacks.

Answer (score 4):

An explicit cast is required.

```
if (a == (Foo){1, 2})
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the expression containing the user defined type a and == operator
Overloaded operator function gets called which as per definition you have given requires an argument of a reference of an object of class Foo

so your expression should be like a==b

where b is an object of class Foo

Here with this expression you will be able to compare data members of b and a and hence know if they are equal or not

Answer (score 0):

No real reason.

C++ is the result of a committee effort so sometimes strange but deliberate decisions may slip through because of complex political/sociological dynamics.

C++ syntax is hard. Very hard. Almost unbelievably hard. There are rules even go like "if you can parse this arbitrarily long sequence of tokens as both this or that, then it's this".

It took many years for compilers even to simply agree on what is C++ and what is not.

In this case my wild guess is that they didn't like the idea that cases that looked very similar:

```
MyClass x = {...};
MyClass y; y = {...};
```

would be handled differently so there is a special provision for assignment to allow the syntax.

From a technical point of view I don't see what are the problems of allowing it for other operators too, and on the other hand if there are problems (e.g. for overloading, template instantiation etc.) I don't see how assignment can hope to escape them.

## EDIT

g++ allows using not only strict `operator=` but also `operator+=`, `operator-=` and similar "augmented assignment". May be the logical problems happens only if you allow non-member overloads (that are forbidden for assignment and augmented assignment operators).